# How to run in atom a command in the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, atom-editor

I'm doing a school project about changing my wallpaper from python and it works in the terminal perfectly but I need to do it from my text editor, atom, and it doesn't seem to work. I've tried rearranging the apostrophes as maybe it's that, but can't seem to make it work.

This works on the terminal perfectly:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set picture of every desktop to ("/Users/carlaa/Desktop/DEVf/python/APODkata/apodimage.jpg" as POSIX file as alias)'
```

but from atom in says invalid syntax

```
from subprocess import call
subprocess.call(["osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set picture of every desktop to ("/Users/carlaa/Desktop/DEVf/python/APODkata/apodimage.jpg" as POSIX file as alias)'",shell=True])
```

Comment: Give it a try on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape those double quotes and remove `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to set picture of every desktop to (\"/Users/carlaa/Desktop/DEVf/python/APODkata/apodimage.jpg\" as POSIX file as alias)'", shell=True])
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I keep getting invalid Syntax.

Comment: @Carla Do you mind updating your question with the exact error you are getting and also try to execute the python script in your terminal rather than atoms?